# toy/doc undefined method 'available?'

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to build local Ruby documentation as suggested here:

https://github.com/toy/doc

However when I use the default Rakefile I get the following:

```
[Documentation]$ rake build
configuring and updating: 100.0%
rake aborted!
undefined method `available?' for Gem:Module
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sdoc-0.2.20/lib/sdoc/json_backend.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Gem::Module#available?` is deprecated by the version of rubygems 2. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/pull/491

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ruby (and even less about the gem ecosystem built up around it), but I believe a *possible workaround* for this issue is to find what gems the project requires and manually install them. In the case of this particular project, it looks like you need the gem "fspath".

At the project root, type

```
gem install fspath
```

and try re-running rake.

I honestly don't know the actual root cause of the issue, other than that presumably, your version of the 'gem' program is probably > v2, while some other program (rake?) expects it to be older and still support the "available?" method.

If installing "fspath" doesn't fix the issue, you could try downgrading your version of gem by doing

```
gem install -v [some version of gem older than v2]
```

Check gem install --help for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for future visitor who has the same issue.

As ekremkaraca said, you can just solve this by downgrading rubygems.

`rvm install --force rubygems 1.4.2`